# Create a new cmd.exe window from within another cmd.exe prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am in the process of setting up CruiseControl.NET. The problem I am having is that I am running CC as a console application and when my build completes successfully and executes (using exec) it launches it within the CruiseControl DOS prompt. I am just using simple batch files to launch my app but having it run within the same prompt as CC is causing CC to think the build continues as long as my app runs.

Are there command line parameters to `cmd.exe` that will spawn another separate prompt window?

Comment: cmd.exe is a CUI shell, not a GUI. It doesn't create windows. It uses a console window that's created and managed by an instance of conhost.exe, the console host process. If a CUI program is started normally, initialization code in the base client DLL (kernel32.dll or kernelbase.dll) inherits the parent's console, if any, or allocates a new console, unless it's started with the creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS` (i.e. no console). If it's started with the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` (as CMD's `start` uses), the base DLL always allocates a new console instead of inheriting the parent's.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

I think this works:

```
start cmd.exe
```

Comment: make sure you check out all the different options for start   
"start /?"   
  
/wait and /I can be usefull.

Comment: fwiw, you don't even have to put 'cmd.exe' after start. just the word 'start' will do it.

Comment: start /d <path>
For those who want to set path for new cmd window.
[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) detailed description.

Comment: or just `start`

Answer (score 78):

Here is the code you need:

```
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "Command"
```

Comment: What is the `@cmd` doing? Is there some documentation for it?

Comment: `@` supresses the direct output which normally would show up in the prompt but the command will still be executed.

Comment: I used this, it works but if try to kill the running program by keyboard interrupt ctrl+c, running program does not stop. It only stops when you close the newly opened command prompt window.

Comment: Doesn't work for multi-line commands using `^`. :( Any way to deal with this?

Comment: `@cmd` appears to be redundant here. Exactly the same bahviour without it. I'm assuming `cmd.exe` silents ignores it as it's an invalid option. You can replace `@cmd` with (almost) any old junk and you'll see the same behaviour.

Answer (score 46):

Simply type `start` in the command prompt:

```
start
```

This will open up new `cmd` windows.

Answer (score 22):

```
start cmd.exe
```

opens a separate window

```
start file.cmd
```

opens the batch file and executes it in another command prompt

Answer (score 6):

You can just type these 3 commands from command prompt:

1. `start`
2. `start cmd`
3. `start cmd.exe`

Answer (score 4):

simple write in your bat file

```
@cmd
```

or

```
@cmd /k "command1&command2"
```

Comment: Thanks for the `&` to execute multiple commands in the new prompt. I like to add `exit` so it closes the prompt when the command have finished running.

Answer (score 3):

```
START "notepad.exe"
echo Will launch the notepad.exe application
PAUSE
```

To make any cmd file type, all you have to do is save the contents as .bat, i.e.

```
@echo
TITLE example.bat
PAUSE
taskkill/IM cmd.exe
```

Make that into an "example.bat" file, save it, then open it and run.

Answer (score 2):

launch_stack.bat will open 2 windows to run your alices.bat and bobs.bat

```
start alices.bat
start bobs.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

If we simply use `start` command or `start cmd.exe` it opens cmd.

If you want to open the same command prompt window;

```
start "Command Prompt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried executing batch file that run daemon process/server at the end of CCNET task; 
The only way to make CruiseControl spawn an independent asynchronous process WITHOUT waiting for the end of process is:

1. create a batch file to run the daemon process (server application)
2. use task scheduler to run the batch file as CCNET task (using schtasks.exe)

   ```
   schtasks.exe /create /F /SC once /ST 08:50 /TN TaskName /TR "c:/path/to/batchFileName.bat"
   ```

   - 08:50 is the HH:MM time format

you might need to kill the process at the start of ccnet

PS: the selected answer using "start cmd.exe" does not work; a new command prompt is indeed spawned, but CCNET will wait for the spawned cmd to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in command line this command

> `cmd`

Previous command will open in current command line `with new session`

OR

> `start`

Answer (score 0):

```
conhost
```

Optionally, `conhost program`, e.g. `conhost powershell`