# Perl: Issue command in new cmd.exe

Tags: windows, perl, command, command-prompt

I want to program in Perl a very basic program but I'm having some questions about how to do it. I'll keep it simple:
I want a perl script that when number 1 is pressed a new "cmd.exe" is opened and the "dir" command is executed, and when 2 is pressed a new "cmd.exe" is opened and the command "cd" is executed.

The place where I'm having the problems is in opening a NEW "cmd.exe" instead of the same cmd that executes the perl script.

Some ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Firstly I don't see the point of doing this. Secondly it'd be nice if you explained *how* you're trying to do this and your current results.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303838/create-a-new-cmd-exe-window-from-within-another-cmd-exe-prompt

Answer (score 2):

If i understand it correct,what you want is to open a new window of cmd.exe and want to execute dir or cd command.is it?
Then i think you can use following command to get it donw

`start cmd /K dir` this command will execute "dir" command but won't close the new command window...

`start cmd /C dir` this command will execute the dir command and terminate the new command window.

Comment: Anil, you have understood perfectly. It works great! Thank you.

Comment: @user354427 You haven't replied to @gamen question as i am also willing to know how you are trying. Any way, if you are satisfy with  answer given by @Anil then pl. accept it