# subprocess.Popen in different console

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I hope this is not a duplicate.

I'm trying to use `subprocess.Popen()` to open a script in a separate console. I've tried setting the `shell=True` parameter but that didn't do the trick.

I use a 32 bit Python 2.7 on a 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: You didn't show an actual code base, so i just made up a command example below based on `dir` in windows and `ls` in linux for listing folder contents.

Comment: @Torxed I tried your code and there are a few things that I don't like: I don't see a new console poping up. I would like a second console to be created and to be able to read the output of the program that I run with `popen` in the new console. In my main program, I don't need the output of the program I run with `popen`. I just need to see it in a different console. Could you please provide an example of how this should be implemented?

Comment: That wasn't clear from your original problem description, because you see, "open a script in a separate console" that's exactly what `.Popen()` does, and if you check your process monitor you'll notice that a cmd.exe is launched from you calling `.Popen()`, it's just not visible because it's a subprocess to your application and it's "muted".
You don't typically open new GUI windows just to execute tasks, so may i ask why you want this? because it sounds backwards to me :/

Comment: Thank you... Also, how would I be able to make my main program wait until the second console finishes execution and then get the return code?

Comment: IMO, Don't open a extra GUI. execute `X` with my first example, grab the exit code and print only valuable information if needed and ignore the rest of the output. It's faster and more elegant. Anyways, `os.system()` gives you the returncode of your command and the program will wait for the command to finish since you're not utelizing threads, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html for help with threads.

Comment: I do get the exit code but the proble is that I see the output of the program I run with `os.system` in the same windows that calls the previously mentioned function. It does not appear in a seprate console. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: See my edit using `start` on windows, also, try googling that.. it's the first hit for "python windows open new console"

Comment: related: [How can I spawn new shells to run python scripts from a base python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6469655/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from subprocess import *

c = 'dir' #Windows

handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
print handle.stdout.read()
handle.flush()
```

If you don't use `shell=True` you'll have to supply `Popen()` with a list instead of a command string, example:

```
c = ['ls', '-l'] #Linux
```

and then open it without shell.

```
handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print handle.stdout.read()
handle.flush()
```

This is the most manual and flexible way you can call a subprocess from Python.
If you just want the output, go for:

```
from subproccess import check_output
print check_output('dir')
```

---

## To open a new console GUI window and execute X:

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /K dir") #/K remains the window, /C executes and dies (popup)
```

Answer (score 67):

To open in a different console, do (tested on Win7 / Python 3):

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Popen('cmd', creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

input('Enter to exit from Python script...')
```

## Related

[How can I spawn new shells to run python scripts from a base python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6469655/1882644)

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thanks :) ... now I have to set a tempo before launching my other task ...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The solid way of opening a new console window in Windows is explicitly supplying the WINAPI process creation flags. Other solutions rely on Python implementation side-effects.

Comment: Read way too much comments before testing this solution. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux shell=True will do the trick:

`command = 'python someFile.py'
subprocess.Popen('xterm -hold -e "%s"' % command)`

Doesn't work with gnome-terminal as described here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180103