# Create new console for the same process

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how to create a new console to print stuff, that is, have more than one stdout available.
After reading some questions, I only managed to do this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
handle = Popen("cmd", stdin=PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
i.write(b'hello')
```

But the message doesnt show up on the new console.

What are my options?

Comment: Where do you want the output to go?  Do you want it interleaved with your program's output, or sent to a file, or somewhere else?  Is that "somewhere else" a thing with a `.write()` method?  It's not clear to me what you're expecting to see.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15899818/4179775

Comment: @Kevin I want to print to print some stuff on one console and other stuff on another console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough I didnt find how to directly create new sdtouts from new consoles, I managed to get the same effect using inter-process communication pipes.

### new_console.py

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import sys

address = '\\\\.\pipe\\new_console'
conn = Client(address)
while True:
    print(conn.recv())
```

### console_factory.py

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

address = '\\\\.\pipe\\new_console'
listener = Listener(address)

def new_console():
    Popen("python new_console.py", creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    return listener.accept()

c1 = new_console()
c1.send("console 1 ready")
c2 = new_console()
c2.send("console 2 ready")
```

Further improvements include sending input from new consoles to the main process, using select in the loop.