# python subprocess use cmd for print() commands

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python code that should execute another code in some other file.

For reasons I don't have the time to explain now I need to use the `subprocess`-module or something similar. My fuction should use any window in which the `print`- commands in my second file should give their output. Here are my files:

maincode.py:

```
#import subprocess

def startFileInNewProcess(filename):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", filename], shell=True)

startFileInNewProcess("mysecondfile.py")
```

mysecondfile.py:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

As far as I undestood some articles on SO, the parameter `shell=True` should create a new window with the output of the `mysecondfile.py`. This does not happen! Can anybody explain why and please give improvement proposals...

Comment: I'm on a debian system, more detailed: Raspbian

Comment: No, `shell=True` doesn't create a new window. It just means that the specified command will be executed through the shell. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: No, `shell=True` causes the first argument to be converted to a string and used as an argument to `sh -c`. You don't want `shell=True` if you are passing a list.

Comment: Here are some other helpful links, related questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899798/subprocess-popen-in-different-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `shell=True` will only execute the command in a shell, in the default shell in your system `/bin/sh`. To start a new terminal window, you need to specify the terminal:

`subprocess.Popen(["xterm", "python"])`

The above line opens a new xterm terminal window and executes `python` command in it.

Comment: I applie your proposal to my code and got this presuming that `filename` is executable: `subprocess.Popen(["xterm", "./"+filename])` This does not wait until I pressed enter or something similar, but codes the window immediately afer end of the program...

Answer (score 0):

on windows you can open a new cmd window and execute the code on that

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

def startFileInNewProcess(filename):
    terminal='cmd'
    command='Python'
    command=terminal +' '+ '/K' +' '+command+' '+filename
    #/K keeps the command prompt open when execution takes place
    #CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE opens a new console
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm on linux, but thanks for the proposal.