# python - Use new created shell and send commands to it

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479468/python-subprocess-use-cmd-for-print-commands) question I asked about creating a new terminal  and start another python program int it from a python program and managed to do it. In the answer I accepted I was told, that

```
subprocess.Popen(["xterm", "python"])
```

would open a new terminal window and start the python interpreter in it.

How can I send commands to that window so that "magically" there can appear any python code to be processed py the interpreter?

Comment: When you say "send commands" do you mean you want to "type" programmatically some characters into the Python interpreter in the launched xterm?  Can you explain more why you're trying to do this?  It is highly unusual.

Comment: Firtt Question: Exactly! You got what I mean. IN the best case somebody could tell me how to "press enter" from my other program as well.

Comment: Second Question: I'm writing a learner's program and want a "demo" button that resolves exercises by live demonstration

Comment: OK...what OS are you using?  This is not possible in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Raspbian, so basically all debian stuff works on there