# A new text-mode window in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, terminal, pyglet

I've used `Tkinter` or `wxWidgets` for some projects: this opens a new window in graphical mode (GUI) in which you can do what you want.

Can I ask Python **to open a new text-mode window** (let's say 80x25 terminal), independant from the terminal where I run `myscript.py`,
in the same way that a Tkinter window is independant from the current terminal where I run `myscript.py`?

What do I want to achieve? Having a GUI, but in textmode! (this might sound tricky because *G* in GUI means graphical!)

**Does tkInter, wxWidget, pyglet, etc. have a feature to open a text-mode terminal-look GUI? With 80x25 text display?**

Comment: Does using xterm work for your purposes?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7331836/4131059

Comment: No it should be crossplatform (including Windows)

Comment: do you mean [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) or  [urwid](http://urwid.org/) ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Windows, see Requirements on http://urwid.org/

Comment: You may have to do it differently on windows (maybe run 'start cmd.exe' but I'm not sure). But that's just a quick `if platform.system() == 'Windows'`.

Comment: Then I should re-phrase: does using the default command prompt and embedding it in a widget work for your application?

Comment: If you're really just looking to make a cross platform text UI, is [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) any use for you?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to make a seperate script but it works.

Use this code in your launcher script.

```
from sys import executable
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Popen([executable, 'myscript.py'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

input('Enter to exit from this launcher script...')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20613015/5168028)