# Open script in a new shell via script

Tags: python, shell, python-3.6, multiprocess

I'd like to run a script (`scriptA`) that will execute another script (`scriptB`) in another window while `scriptA` is still running.

I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'scriptB.py'])
```

but it runs `scriptB` in the `scriptA`'s window.

Could someone help me?

EDIT : 
As pointed out in the commentary, the flag creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE found by emiguel ( [How can I spawn new shells to run python scripts from a base python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469655/how-can-i-spawn-new-shells-to-run-python-scripts-from-a-base-python-script) ) works perfectly.

Thanks :)

Comment: May be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469655/how-can-i-spawn-new-shells-to-run-python-scripts-from-a-base-python-script

Comment: Try using python [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module