# python import from subprocess fails

Tags: python, makefile

I have been working on some makefiles which call some python scripts to perform various tasks. Up to now, I had always been `make`ing on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bits) installed. Today, I have tried building on my old 32 bits machine with Lubuntu 16.04 using the same makefile and it fails when calling the Python script.

At first, I thought that my Python version was not new enough, but I also have Python 3.5 installed and I changed the line to `python3` in the makefile and it still fails:

```
python3 /home/morane/Documents/Programming/ConnectX/cxPythonTools/RunUnitTests.py -t /home/morane/bin/tests/unit/cxUnitTests.out -l /home/morane/bin/tests/unit/log/unitTests.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morane/RunUnitTests.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
ImportError: cannot import name 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'unittests' failed
make: *** [cxbaseunit] Error
```

To test, I have tried to repeat the error directly in the Python shell:

```
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'
```

and it still fails. Does anyone know whats going on?

Regards

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you're running in Linux. The `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` constant is only available on Windows.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Specifically the header of section 17.5.4:

> The STARTUPINFO class and following constants are only available on Windows.

Comment: You are right, but why is it working on my Linux 64 bit OS? I don't even get a warning.

Comment: In my intro it says it works on my Ubuntu 64 bit machine. If I am not clear enough please tell me I'll edit it.

Comment: As for that....I'm not really sure. Do you mind sharing the contents of RunUnitTests.py? Also apologies for the previous comment, I didn't fully read the intro (my bad!).

Comment: Of course, here: https://github.com/BobMorane22/ConnectX/blob/dev/cxPythonTools/RunUnitTests.py

Comment: Hmm...I may be missing something entirely, but it would appear that `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` isn't used in the unit tests file after you import it. Would it be possible to simply remove it?

Comment: It is unused (it's a left-over from previous code) but I'm just wondering what's bothering my 32-bit OS