# Child Process with shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, npm, child-process

I'm trying to spawn a child process with separate shell output/input (It also needs input preferably), but I can't make it work.

File 1 (Main): **index.js**

File 2 (Child): **kahoot.js**

I want File 1 to spawn File 2 as child_process with separate shell. I have been bugging myself with this one for days, thanks!

Comment: By "separate shell" you mean it should open another terminal window or what?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more specific on that. If possible a CMD process

Comment: I guess by `cmd` you mean you're on windows. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19773173/133203) answer helps.

Comment: That helps, but how would I perform that command as child_process?